# Collections.binarySearch vs TreeSet

Tags: java

I have a collection of data to search using binary search. Now in Java, I found the method `Collections.binarySearch()` which implements the binary search while the `TreeSet` class internally also uses the Red-Black tree to search which is the same as binary search.

The question is which method or class should I use? Any pros and cons?

Comment: Apples to oranges! Do you build a collection of things, sort it once then search it? Or do you have a collection of things that you are constantly adding and removing from that needs to stay sorted? Is your sorting requirement consistent with equals? Are the objects you are sorting unique by comparison (never compared the same)?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this a opinion based - how is a request for the differences between algorithms (a purely technical question) a matter of opinion??